# hubspot api access but client_id

Tags: api, authentication, oauth, token, hubspot

I am trying to parse some data using hubspot api by given demo account. To have a proper response you need client_id within parameters. It says, I can find my client_id inside app dashboard. Can someone please tell me what is the exact client_id inside dashboard or what is the client parameter for tokens.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You would get the client_id by creating an app from the Developers dashboard, not your portal dashboard.  If you haven't created an app yet, you would first need to sign in and then go here:
https://app.hubspot.com/developers/signup

If you haven't signed up yet, you can sign up there to create a Developers account, otherwise you'll get directed to the My Apps Dashboard.  click the blue Create App button in the top right to create an app, and after the app is created you can click on the app name from the App Dashboard to get the Client ID.